# Handling multiple keys down in a multiplayer game

Tags: c#, .net, 2d-games

I am coding my own game using Windows Forms Applications. It is supposed to be a multiplayer game. Every player can control its brick to keep the ball in the pitch, but the problem is that both players cannot press controls at the same time. Every time the second player presses the key during the movement of the first, the brick of the first player stops. But, if they press the keys at the same tame, both bricks move. I used the **KeyDown** event:

```
  private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W && one.BrickLocationY > 0)
        {
            one.BrickLocationY -= 17;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S && one.BrickLocationY + Brick.BrickHeight < screenHeight)
        {
            one.BrickLocationY += 17;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            two.BrickLocationY -= 17;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down && two.BrickLocationY + Brick.BrickHeight < screenHeight)
        {
            two.BrickLocationY += 17;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Ok, this allows me to move the brick up and down. If I press two keys at once, both bricks move in the wanted direction. The bricks are drawn on a paint event triggered by the timer tick whose interval is set to 1.

```
  private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(ellipsePen, x, y, ballSize, ballSize );
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.White ,x+1, y+1, ballSize, ballSize);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, one.BrickLocationX+1, one.BrickLocationY+1, Brick.BrickWidth, Brick.BrickHeight);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, two.BrickLocationX+1, two.BrickLocationY+1, Brick.BrickWidth, Brick.BrickHeight);
    }
```

I also had attempts to do this with the combination of **KeyUp** and **KeyPress** but with no success. The only thing that came to my mind was threading bricks, but had no idea how to do it. I there any way I can handle multiplayer controls like this without threading?

P.S.The keyboard is capable of handling multiple buttons at once.

Comment: winforms is not intended to be used for game development. use XNA or at least WPF.

Answer (score 1):

When the KeyDown event fires, you need to check which buttons are pressed every time. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c7f4542f-c1c5-4cfa-ac04-521d4e7ef1a5/c-detect-multiple-keypress) is what I found upon a quick search on the topic.

```
using System; 
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);
      tm.Tick += new System.EventHandler(DoSomethingWithKeyboardInput);
      this.Load += new System.EventHandler(Form1_Load);
      textBox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(textbox1_KeyDown);
      textBox1.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(textbox1_KeyDown);
    }

    private Timer tm = new Timer();
    private List<System.Windows.Forms.Keys> MovementKeys = new List<System.Windows.Forms.Keys>();
    private _MyInputKeys MyInputKeys = new _MyInputKeys();

    private struct _MyInputKeys
    {
      public bool Jump;
      public bool Left;
      public bool Right;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
      tm.Stop();
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithKeyboardInput(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      textBox1.Text = (MyInputKeys.Left ? "(left)" : "") + 
        (MyInputKeys.Right ? "(right)" : "") + (MyInputKeys.Jump ? "(jump)" : "");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
      //define keys used for movement

      MovementKeys.Add(Keys.Up); //Jump ?
      MovementKeys.Add(Keys.Left); //Left Arrow - Move Left
      MovementKeys.Add(Keys.Right); //Rigth Arrow - Move Right
      tm.Interval = 50;
      tm.Start();
    }

    private void textbox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
      if (MovementKeys.IndexOf(e.KeyCode) != -1)
      {
        e.Handled = true;
        MyInputKeys.Jump = IsKeyDown(Keys.Up);
        MyInputKeys.Left = IsKeyDown(Keys.Left);
        MyInputKeys.Right = IsKeyDown(Keys.Right);
      }
    }

    public static bool IsKeyDown(Keys key)
    {
      return (GetKeyState(Convert.ToInt16(key)) & 0X80) == 0X80;
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///  If the high-order bit is 1, the key is down; otherwise, it is up.
    ///  If the low-order bit is 1, the key is toggled. 
    ///  A key, such as the CAPS LOCK key, is toggled if it is turned on. 
    ///  The key is off and untoggled if the low-order bit is 0. 
    ///  A toggle key's indicator light (if any) on the keyboard will be on when 
    ///  the key is toggled, and off when the key is untoggled.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nVirtKey"></param>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public extern static Int16 GetKeyState(Int16 nVirtKey);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to track this yourself. Basically on key down you recognize the w and consider it being held until key up releases the w. same with the s key.

Then in your run loop, you just look for what keys are active and do your direction logic there.